# How to listen to custom Svelte event in Jest

Tags: jestjs, svelte

I'm dispatching a custom event from a Svelte component:

```js
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
...
dispatch('navigation', result);
```

How can I listen for this event using Jest?

I can't find anything in the [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started) docs, [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/api) docs or [Svelte Jester](https://github.com/mihar-22/svelte-jester) which demonstrates how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can do so this way:

```js
const { getByTestId, component } = render(SLink, {
    props: { id: 'khjb23' },
});

const link = getByTestId('khjb23');

component.$on('navigation', e => {
    console.log(e.detail); // Dispatched value
});
```